# Semantic UI Error on search

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui, nette

When I use a Semantic UI search with jQuery, I have a some problems:

> API: API action used but no url was defined search Object {}
>
> API: No URL specified for api event

My code:

```
 $('#product_name').keyup(function() {
      if($(this).val().length >= 2) 
      {
          $.getJSON('http://localhost/eval/www/validations/add/' + $(this).val() + '?do=findProducts', function(payload) {
              var content = payload.products;
              $('.ui.search').search({
                  source: content
              });
              console.log('Data: ',content);
          });
      }
  });
```

In content a had a right data, but with this errors? Can you help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using semantic ui and want to get data from server side then you should use it as like below.

```
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    minCharacters : 2,
    apiSettings: {
      url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}'
    },
    fields: {
      results : 'items',
      title   : 'name',
      url     : 'html_url'
    }
  })
;
```

as mentioned on semantic side. You can also control min key input using 
minCharacters as given above example. it will start search when it gets 2 char input.

Comment: I know about this, but my variable content is type of json array

Comment: above example is also getting res in json array. Have you tried this approach?